# How does people directly get above 100 rep immediately?

Tags: bug

I have seen some users here that are new and haven't posted anything that is, no user activity. How come these people have reputation of above 100 without doing anything. I found this while I was checking the users tab.

I could share the user's profile if requested but of course I am not blaming anyone. It might be a bug or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because those users have gotten the reps from an associated bonus.

If a user have 200 or more reputation on at least one Stack Exchange site that user will automatically get 100 reputation when joining other sites on the Stack Exchange network.

See: [What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Comment: I didn't know this. Maybe it was to counter the initial requirements for reputation on commenting. Thanks :)